# Function doesn't execute the read.csv lines

Tags: r

In the beginning of my code I am trying to execute the following lines:

```
links <- read.csv("/<mypath>.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
nodes <- read.csv("/<mypath>.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
```

I want my code to do this when I do load all.

I wrote:

```
data_load <- function(){
     links <- read.csv("/<mypath>.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
     nodes <- read.csv("/<mypath>.csv", header=T, as.is=T)
}
data_load()
```

but it didn't work the way I wanted, my environment is still empty. Any ideas? 
Sorry for questions I am a newby in R.

Comment: Your function is not returning anything...

Comment: @Wimpel Should I return links and nodes?

Comment: Why would you want to wrap a function around reading data? If you don't want to have a bunch of import statements, import the .`csv` files once, save the workspace, and from then on import the workspace instead of the `.csv` files.

Comment: @apitsch I want my code to work when I do Build > Load All. It prompts the user and according to the choice it executes a code block but my data should be ready for it beforehand, I will make the user to choose at some point, it will be a package

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to return your results from inside the function.

```
data_load <- function(){
    links <- read.csv("vpn.txt", header=T, as.is=T)
    nodes <- read.csv("vpn.txt", header=T, as.is=T)
    return(list(links=links, nodes=nodes))
}

data=data_load()
links=data$links
nodes=data$nodes
```

Comment: That's one way to do it. But return the list you've created in the function :)

Comment: The last line in the function should be `return(list(links=links, nodes=nodes))`.

Comment: @apitsch I should be able to see links and nodes under environment right? on Rstudio? Because I already wrote it as return but I can see either of them

Comment: @C.J ... Are you assigning the function to an object? Your original post only called the function `data_load()`.

Comment: @Parfait I used the above code, it didn't work either. Well 
`data_load <- function(){}` 
was my first idea. I want to learn a good way because I want the same thing for 
`net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=links, vertices=nodes, directed=T) <br>
net <- simplify(net, remove.multiple = F, remove.loops = T)<br>
net <br>
mycolours <- c("steelblue", "orange")<br>
V(net)$color <- mycolours[V(net)$node.group] `

Comment: You seem to be asking a different question.

Comment: @Parfait For now all I need is a code like above, but when I do Build > Load All I want to see the links and nodes in environment section on Rstudio. The code above doesn't make me see links and nodes in environment. When I choose `read.csv()` lines and run them I see them there

Comment: I accepted it since even though I haven't seen the data under environment it works.